# Replace value in json from another json

Tags: json, dictionary, jq

I have a json file with the following format:

```
{userid: 1, client_visited: [1001, 1002]}
{userid: 2, client_visited: [1001, 1004]}
{userid: 3, client_visited: [1004, 1006]}
{userid: 4, client_visited: [1003, 1005, 1006]}
{userid: 5, client_visited: [1006]}
```

I have a mapping of clients that is output from MYSQL db:

```
{"1001": a, "1002": b, "1003": c, "1004": d, "1005": e, "1006": f}
```

How can I update the above json file for the following output?

```
{userid: 1, client_visited: ['a', 'b']}
{userid: 2, client_visited: ['a', 'd']}
{userid: 3, client_visited: ['d', 'f']}
{userid: 4, client_visited: ['c', 'e', 'f']}
{userid: 5, client_visited: ['f']}
```

I am looking at `jq` command to achieve this in a shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, jq is a JSON processor, so you will have to convert your file and dictionary to valid JSON.  (For some guidance in doing so, see the [jq FAQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ)).

Second, you haven't indicated where the dictionary is to be found.  In the following, I'll assume it can be included in the program file but there are many other options (see e.g. the manual regarding --argjson).

Third, there are various ways to specify a program.  I'll assume you have the following in a file named program.jq:

```
def dict: {"1001": "a", "1002": "b", "1003": "c", "1004": "d", "1005": 
"e", "1006": "f"};

.client_visited |= map(dict[tostring])
```

The invocation: jq -f program.jq input.json

yields the desired result (but of course it will be valid JSON).

### Postscript

In the comments, the OP asked about using a distinguished value rather than null should the dictionary be missing a lookup value.  To do so, consider:

```
.client_visited |= map(tostring as $s
                       | if dict|has($s) then dict[$s] else 0 end)
```

The following might also be worth considering:

```
.client_visited |= map(dict[tostring] // 0)
```

Comment: can we do it using `--argjson`?

Comment: Working!! But I would definitely like a solution so that I don't have to create a new file `program.jq`

Comment: As I said, I'd suggest using --argfile for the dictionary, and that way, the program will easily fit on the command line.  See the online user manual.

Comment: I get null for the values that are not matched, can I replace this with 0 if the value is not found in mapping.

Comment: Sure. You could write an if...then...else...end, or maybe simply replace dict[tostring] by dict[tostring] // 0

Comment: This works...maybe you should update your answer with this.

Answer (score 0):

Not as succinct as [peak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997358/peak)'s answer but here is a solution using **reduce** to iterate over the indices of `client_visited` updating each element.

```
reduce (.client_visited|range(length)) as $i (
    .
  ; .client_visited[$i] |= $arg[tostring]
)
```

To specify `$arg` you can use `--argfile` and invoke with something like

```
jq --argfile arg mapping.json -f filter.jq data.json
```